# APISubscriptionError instagram API private network

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying set up a instagram subscription on my localhost with the Instagram-node nodeJs API, but when I launch this code I got this error :

```
{ [Error: APISubscriptionError: Invalid URL. The URL may be on a private network.]
  code: 400,
  error_type: 'APISubscriptionError',
  error_message: 'Invalid URL. The URL may be on a private network.',
  retry: [Function] } undefined
```

---

the code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var api = require('instagram-node').instagram();

api.use({access_token : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'})
api.use({
client_id:'xxxxxxxxxx',
client_secret:'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'

});

var redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/callback';


api.add_geography_subscription(48.565464564, 2.34656589, 100, 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/callback',
    {}, 
    function(err, result, remaining, limit){
        console.log(err,result)

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram or anybody esle cannot access your `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as this IP address is just known and accessible on your computer itself.
You have to register the callback on a public IP address or domain and host your application there.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but for your information Twitter can do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently building an app using NodeJS and Instagram Real-time API myself. The answer to this is to use something like http://localtunnel.me/. You could also host your app on something like [Heroku](http://heroku.com) as well.

The marked answer is only partially correct.

Comment: What do you have to set as callback_url and redirect_uri when using localtunnel? Thanks